# Does using a LinkedBlockingQueue between two threads mean we don't need to synchronize their access to shared data?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a situation where a project I'm maintaining contains a piece of code where:

1. A thread `T1` periodically updates a field of type `List<String>` then adds a value to a `LinkedBlockingQueue`:

   ```java
   // ctor
   List<String> list = null;
   queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue(); // Integer.MAX_VALUE capacity

   // Thread T1
   list = getNewList();
   queue.offer(/* some value */);
   ```
2. Another thread `T2` periodically polls `queue` and, upon receiving a certain value, reads `list`:

   ```java
   // Thread T2
   Object value = queue.poll();
   if (Objects.equals(value, /* some desired value */) {
       // Read `list` in (1)
   }
   ```

The thing that caught my attention was the lack of synchronization between the two threads as they accessed `list` (was not marked `volatile` either), which made me think there could be a data race in that code. However, when I referred to [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), I found a sentence that says:

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a BlockingQueue happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the BlockingQueue in another thread.

Does this mean that `T2` is always guaranteed to observe the changes made by `T1` to `list` and no data race is possible?

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed by java memory model as stated in javadoc

Comment: Happens the first step only once?

Comment: Sharing a non-protected list between threads is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's a particular instance of an effect that's more generally [described here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html) (the [memory consistency errors link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) on that page is especially worth reading.

*All of these collections help avoid Memory Consistency Errors by defining a happens-before relationship between an operation that adds an object to the collection with subsequent operations that access or remove that object.*

So, more generally, when you have two pieces of code like this:

```
// list is a non thread safe ArrayList
list.add("abcd");
// col is *any* java.util.concurrent collection
col.add(anObject); // or put, or offer...
```

and

```
if (col.get() == anObject) { … } // or poll etc.
```

If the second piece of code is executed by other thread than the first piece (and the condition is true), any code placed after the retrieval of `anObject` can see "abcd" added to the list.

But:

- it has to be *the same* object (`anObject`, the stuff you put/get from concurrent collection)
- it's assuming after `col.addObject(anObject)` call, the list wasn't further modified
- it (obviously, but worth noting) has to have been actually put into the collection. `offer()` might have returned false in that other thread and `poll()` might have timed out in this one.

Comment: `col.get(anObject);` is very misleading, as normally you don’t tell a query method what to return. Since you correctly named the constraints about the query returning the same object, it would make sense to use `if(col.get() == anObject) { … }` to demonstrate the only valid use case. It’s also worth adding that it only works if `anObject` is never added more than once and further, no modifications to `list` or its elements happen after the `col.add(anObject);` operation.

Comment: Thanks @Holger, updated the answer. How would a modification of one of the list's elements play a role here? (the "...or its elements" part of your comment)

Comment: @pafauk. the guarantee is that any write in T1 before the `col.add` is visible by T2 after `col.get`. But if T1 continues to write to `list` or to modify the objects inside `list` (e.g. list.get(0).setTitle("newTitle")) after the `col.add`, then all bets are off untill T1 and T2 *both* perform another `col.add`/ `col.get` (or a similar happens-before boundary)

Comment: People tend to generalize, so for the case you have a list of something other than immutable types like string, modifications to the contained elements are subject to the same rules as modifications to the list.

Comment: I thought you were saying messing with list elements *other* than `anObject` would somehow mess with visibility of changes done prior to store/retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

**Does this mean that T2 is always guaranteed to observe the changes made by T1 to list and no data race is possible?**

You are protected by the memory model in the sense that the changes to the list BEFORE ADDING TO THE QUEUE will be visible to the second thread before the second thread sees them.

Otherwise these Queue's won't be very useful.

But for any changes done later. All bets are off.

**Periodic Updates**

You said: T1 periodically updates a field of type List and then adds it to the queue.

If by field you mean some instance variable or static variable.
And by periodically, you mean that you mutate it from T1 after you have put it in the queue.

Then I'd say that you most definitely are going to have trouble. The best course of action would be to send a COPY of the list like this:

```
list = getNewList();
queue.offer(new ArrayList<String>(list));
```

Its best you aren't sharing objects between the threads. Just create it and send it.

In fact, it doesn't make sense to send a shared list through the queue. You might as well just share it all the time (in some protected fashion).

The reason you use a queue is that you want to send a message to the other thread, and at that point you should release it, and do nothing else.

**Memory model**

Again, the memory model will guarantee that the object is good once it gets to the other thread. So visibility won't be a problem as long as T1 (or any other thread) no longer does anything to the object.

**Note on live objects**

Regardless of what you do, beware of queueing "live objects" like Hibernate controlled objects and things that are intended to live for a very short time. When I've used this feature I generally send over id's and things like that so T2 can restore the object from the database independently and not hang on to objects that were managed in another thread.

So you need to be careful about what you put in the list as well. Immutable strings are ok, of course.